Ideas to cover water meter in backyard
My girlfriend is buying a town house and already signed the contract. She later saw something in the backyard that went originally unnoticed: the water meters for her home and the other units in the community (see picture below)
Her plan was to put an outdoor-protected TV in that wall, right where the meters are. Now we are wondering if there is still a way to do it or the TV will have to go somewhere else. A few ideas we had so far:

Build a closet around the water meters (and maybe the AC compressor) with a door, providing access for anyone who needs to work on the AC or water meters while still being able to hang the TV in the outside of this closet. This would use up some backyard space, of course.
Build a mobile wood screen that goes in front of the water meters, hang the TV on the screen and move it when needed.
Buy a mobile outdoor TV stand and just put it in front of the meters when we want to watch TV.
Cover the water meters with plants and put the TV somewhere else.

I'm wondering if there are any other options we are not thinking about, or if some of these ideas are actually undoable. Any thoughts?


Water and/or electric meters are owned/controlled by utility and need their permission to place anything near/covering them.

those don't look like water meters

you probably need permission before attaching anything to the building ... you may not be allowed to attach the TV anywhere

Is there a body corp in the community? If so, you need to ask them.

Those are electric meters.  You cannot use anything to block axcess to them. The "closet" idea may work , but there is minimum open air space that is needed. Your location may have additional restrictions and codes.
Additionally there may be restrictions regarding the modification of any part of the exterior of the structure.   You should plan on changing the placement of the TV and get approval from the HOA before building anything.
